# Probability with volumes of a cuboid

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you are allowed to choose any 6 random numbers from ${1,2,3,\cdots,999}$.
Let three of them be $a_1,a_2,a_3$ then the remaining three be $b_1,b_2,b_3$. Then what is the probability that box with dimensions of $a_i$ fits into box of $b_i$. Note that the box can be rotated before placing. Now i took numbers numbers $1,2,3,4,5,6$. Now I saw that for all possible $20$ cases $5$ are favorable. But how do i prove that its true for general $i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5,i+6$ also any random collection of $6$ numbers. Is the induction the way? Or any other way? Thanks

Comment: Must those randomly picked numbers be consecutive like $i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5$?

Comment: if you've got the values ordered in in creasing size (a1,a2,a3) and (b1,b2,b3) then a1<=b1, a2<=b2, a3<=b3 and the values themselves are 'order statistics' with a probability distribution

Comment: @stud_iisc No they are random.

Comment: I would be better if i could prove for any random numbers

Comment: I think Cato's point was that once you have chosen them at random you would then order them so that $a_i$ has the best chance of fitting into $b_i$. In other words, you will want to ignore permutations, so for example choosing $(1, 2, 3)$ at random should be counted the same as choosing $(2, 3, 1)$.

Comment: This also gets a bit more complicated since sometimes a box that's slightly too wide to fit into another box can be fit by rotating less than 90 degrees so that just ordering the dimensions is not necessarily enough to show that one fits inside the other.

Comment: Consider $AAABBB, AABABB, AABBAB, ABAABB, ABABAB$